Involution of second kind in semisimple algebras
On page 20 of the book of Involutions, I have read something that I do not understand. Let $B$ be a simple $F$-algebra with centre $K$ and an involution of the second kind $\tau$.
The author said: "In the case of involutions of the second kind on a simple algebra $B$, the base field $F$ is usually not the center of the algebra, but the field of central invariant elements which is of codimension 2 in the center. Under scalar extension to an algebraic closure of $F$, the algebra $B$ decomposes into a direct product of two simple factors."
Then the author said in the case where $K \cong F \times F$, $B \cong B_1 \times B_2$, where $B_1$ and $B_2$ are central simple $F$-algebras.
My confusion stems from the following:
"we refer to $(B, \tau)$ as a central simple $F$-algebra with involution of the second kind, even though its center is not $F$ and the algebra $B$ may not be simple."
"it can be justified by showing that $(B, \tau)$ is indeed central simple as an algebra-with-involution."
How can we justify the last statement?
At first, I thought we can consider a simple $F$-algebra to be central simple $K$-algebra, but then the author said $B$ can even be not simple. Can you give an example?
Let $B=\text{Mat}_n(\mathbb{C})$ as an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra. $B$ is simple $\mathbb{R}$-algebra and central simple $\mathbb{C}$-algebra. By what author said, we can consider $B\cong\text{Mat}_n(\mathbb{R}) \times \text{Mat}_n(\mathbb{R})$ which means $B$ is not a simple $\mathbb{R}$-algebra. What do I miss?
